# Symfony3 database call is taking a long time and it's stopping the entire site from working. How do i close the connection after a certain time?

Tags: nginx, pdo, symfony, fpm

My server setup is php7.0-fpm and nginx with symfony running on top.

I am just using a raw pdo connection

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$results = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM myTable");
```

One of my SQL queries is taking a really long time while also bringing down the site during that time.

I imagine there's some configuration going on that I need to change but I'm a bit of sys-admin/ops beginner.

I tried adding to my php.ini the

```
 default_socket_timeout = 3
```

I tried adding=>

```
options:
     timeout: 3
```

in my symfony config.yml.

Neither worked!

Is there  another way of setting the timeout?  Or is there some other thing going wrong?

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

Comment: That's just a link to the...heyyyy!

Comment: What do you expect of setting a timeout? Instead of a long loading time you will get an error? You should work on your business logic - fetch the data via AJAX for example so your main-page is not blocked while loading.

Comment: how is the error log say (nginx, php, and mysql)?